# How do I change the foreground nav bar color?

Tags: java, android

Within my Android app, I want to change the foreground of the navigation bar from default white to any other color programmatically in Java. 
For instance -

[image]

to

[image]

I've searched Stack Overflow, the web, and Android Developers.
There are many posts about changing the background with

```
getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(mColor);
```

But I can't figure out how to change the foreground. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you verified if this is at all possible? I have never seen this

Comment: I haven't seen it before, I just assumed since you can change the background color to white, you'd be able to at least switch the foreground to black. Is that possible? I guess I don't really need color more than white or black.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, you can hide the system bar and create a custom nav bar with whatever color you want

Comment: Ok thank you. To create a new one, would I just insert it into my layout or is there a specific class for this?

Answer (score 0):

I've searched for same question and got, that color can be changed to light or dark variants only.
So here's my solution for this.

```
    public static void setNavBarForeground(boolean light, Activity activity, View view){
    try {
        if (!light) {//make buttons dark to be more visible
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                WindowInsetsController windowInsetController = activity.getWindow().getInsetsController();
                if (windowInsetController != null)
                    windowInsetController.setSystemBarsAppearance(WindowInsetsController.APPEARANCE_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BARS, WindowInsetsController.APPEARANCE_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BARS);
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR);
            }
        } else { //make buttons light to be more visible
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                WindowInsetsController windowInsetController = activity.getWindow().getInsetsController();
                if (windowInsetController != null)
                    windowInsetController.setSystemBarsAppearance(0, WindowInsetsController.APPEARANCE_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BARS);
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                view.setSystemUiVisibility(0);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Logger.log(e);
    }
}
```